# Pointwise stabiliser of a union of orbits is a normal subgroup

Tags: group-theory, reference-request, solution-verification, group-actions, normal-subgroups

Let a group $G$ act on a set $S$.

Define the set orbit and pointwise stabiliser for all $A\subseteq S$,

\begin{align*}
G\cdot A&:=\{g\cdot a:g\in G,a\in A\}\\
\textrm{Stabp}_G(A)&:=\{g\in G:(\forall a\in A)(g\cdot a = a)\}
\end{align*}

Let $X\subseteq S$. Then we have
$$\textrm{Stabp}_G(G\cdot X)\trianglelefteq G$$

---

I would like a source that refers to this, please. I am interested in this and any related results. I'm quite sure it's true - I wrote a proof, but haven't verified it with someone else. If someone could, that would be great.

If the action is faithful, I also wonder if there is some sort of converse statement that can be made? (Normal subgroup $\implies$ ???)

---

Proof:

By definition, $\textrm{Stabp}_G(G\cdot X)=\{n\in G:(\forall h\in G,x\in X)(n\cdot(h\cdot x)=h\cdot x)\}$.

Let $g\in G$, $n\in\textrm{Stabp}_G(G\cdot X)$. Let $m=gng^{-1}$.

Let $h\in G$, $x\in X$.

Then
\begin{align}
n\cdot (h\cdot x) = h\cdot x
&\iff&
(gng^{-1}ghg^{-1})\cdot x &= (ghg^{-1})\cdot x\\
&\iff&
(mghg^{-1})\cdot x &= (ghg^{-1})\cdot x
\end{align}
Note $gGg^{-1} = G$, so letting $k=ghg^{-1}$, we've shown for all $k\in G$, $x\in X$,
$$(mk)\cdot x= k\cdot x$$
Hence $m=gng^{-1}\in\textrm{Stabp}_G(G\cdot X)$.

Comment: How does $X$ come into play?

Comment: fixed \charcharchar

Comment: Please share your proof.

Comment: Written out, excuse me if I've made a mistake.

Comment: Even shorter, $nhx=hx$ iff $h^{-1}nhx=x$ so that $n$ is in $\operatorname{Stabp}_G(GX)$ if and only if $h^{-1}nh$ is in $\operatorname{Stabp}_G(X)$ for every $h\in G$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out this result is clear to see if you view the action as a homomorphism into the symmetric group of $S$.

If the action is restricted to a union of orbits $G\cdot X$, then $\textrm{Stabp}_G(G\cdot X)$ is the kernel of the action. That explains why I could not find a formulation of the result in this specific way.

---

As for a reverse implication, given an arbritrary set $G$ acts on, it is unlikely for all normal subgroups to be found this way. For example, there may only be one orbit while $G$ could have multiple normal subgroups (eg. let $G$ act on itself). So I will abandon this train of thought.

Comment: Posted this since my question is resolved, although I cannot accept my own answer for a while.